# MySQL Loop Through Column

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I was working on a small project and I found that using the following code to loop through the column values is actually printing it twice.
For example:

```
admin
admin
user
user
...
```

And so on. Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
foreach($row as $elem)
{
echo $elem . "<br/>";
}
}
```

Is the while loop affecting the foreach and is making it execute twice? Maybe a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches the row twice - once with the column as index, and once with a numbered index.

You could use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead, or do `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`, which will only fetch it with the column as a key, rather than both.

Example, a `var_dump()` on the `$row` variable when using `mysqli_fetch_array()` could give

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "admin"
  ["username "]=>
  string(5) "admin"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "user"
  ["username "]=>
  string(4) "user"
}
```

So as you can tell, it fetches the values twice, with different key-indexes. Doing as suggested above (`mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`) would only fetch the following

```
array(1) {
  ["username "]=>
  string(5) "admin"
}
array(1) {
  ["username "]=>
  string(4) "user"
}
```

Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thanks, I had a snippet with the second variable but I deleted the 'MYSQLI_ASSOC' to see what happens without it, thinking that I may google that later. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have cleared it up for you! Usually, the documentation holds the answer if you're ever unsure of something :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $name = $row['username'];   // taking saving row in variable name 
    echo $name . "<br/>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the rows in an array if you want to loop through each element like that.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $elem){
     echo $elem . "<br/>";
}
```

What you're doing now is looping over each row and then each element for every row.  So yes, that would print it twice.

Comment: Nope. It was the mysqli_fetch_ARRAY vs ASSOC.

Comment: Thanks for ansewering, anyway!